# Bash issue with process substitution in a variable

Tags: bash, process, substitution

I'm trying to get a dd command in a bash script going with the "if" set to a variable.
The variable may be /dev/zero or may be as complicated as
<(yes $'\01' | tr -d "\n")

I can seem to get the latter to work.

```
write_file=/dev/zero
dd if=$write_file bs=2048 seek=1 of=/dev/sda count=524288
```

That works.

```
write_file="<(yes $'\01' | tr -d "\n")"
dd if=$write_file bs=2048 seek=1 of=/dev/sda count=524288
```

This doesn't work. I get a

```
dd: invalid option -- 'd'
Try `dd --help' for more information.
```

But If I do a straight

```
dd if=<(yes $'\01' | tr -d "\n") bs=2048 seek=1 of=/dev/sda count=524288
```

in the script it works fine.

I'm sure there is some escaping that needs to be done but I'm no where near a bash expert to figure out how to do this!

Update:  Tried from suggestions below

```
write_file="<(yes $'\01' | tr -d \"\n\")"
dd if="$write_file" bs=2048 seek=1 of=/dev/sda count=524288
```

and got

```
dd: opening `<(yes $\'\\01\' | tr -d "\\n")': No such file or directory
```

Comment: try `dd "if=$write_file" ...`

Comment: Just do it in-line. See [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash does not parse the content of your variable and pass it directly to dd, which has no idea of what to do with it.
You can force Bash to parse the variable using "eval":

```
 write_file="<(yes $'\01' | tr -d \"\n\")"
 command="dd if=$write_file bs=2048 seek=1 of=/dev/sda count=524288"
 eval "${command}"
```

Comment: Ok..  So I just posted my own answer before I refreshed my browser and saw this. D'oh.  Oh well this probably will work the same as just putting the `eval` in front of the dd command.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok..  I guess I needed an "eval" in front of the dd.

so:

```
write_file="<(yes $'\x5a' | tr -d \"\n\")"
eval dd if=$write_file bs=2048 seek=1 of=/dev/sda count=5242
```

Works!  I guess it re-parses after it does the variable substitution or something like that.

I got the hint from [here](http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash%3a_Why_use_eval_with_variable_expansion?)

The funny thing is I tried using `eval` yesterday but I couldn't get it to work.  I must have been missing some quoting or escaping somewhere..